# Bitwise shift operation choice

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Hello everyone I'm learning programming in java and I wanted to know why is the choice for
Sign bit propagation is ">>" and not ">>>"?
I would assume << and >> should have the same implementation.
Sorry if it sounds like a silly question :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<<` is generally referred to as a "signed left shift". Not sure why though.

Comment: The sign bit only matters when shifting right. In a left shift, a signed and unsigned shift are identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. By same implementation I meant same process but opposite direction(sorry if the word was not applicable here). Since << shift bits to left and fill the right with zeros why not make >> do the same thing and use >>> if you want to propagate the sign bit?

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close this.  The duplicate answer explains how >> and >>> work, but it doesn't explain why the operators were chosen the way they were instead of the other way around, which I think is the real question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Both `<<` and `>>>` shift zeroes in.  "Same implementation" is the wrong term, but I understood what OP was trying to say.

Comment: not a silly question, but a bit off-topic for SO imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it works this way is because C and C++ used `<<` for left shift and `>>` for right shift long before Java.  Those languages have both signed and unsigned types, and for signed types the sign bit was propagated in the right-shift case.

Java does not have unsigned types, so they kept the behavior of C and C++ so as not to sow confusion and incur the undying wrath of developers the world over.  Then they included `>>>` to provide a right-shift that treated the bit value as unsigned.

Comment: @Jalearn If you find this answer useful, you should “accept” it by clicking the large green check mark next it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really about reading James Gosling's mind :-).  But my guess is that `<<` and `>>` both make sense mathematically: `<<` causes a number to be multiplied by 2 (barring overflow), and `>>` causes a number to be divided by 2--when you have sign propagation, this works whether the number is positive or negative.  Perhaps the language designers thought this would be a more common use of the right shift than the operator that propagates 0's, which is more useful when integers are treated as strings of bits rather than actual numbers.  Neither way is "right" or "wrong", and it's possible that if Gosling had had something different for breakfast that morning, he might have seen things your way instead...

Comment: Thanks Ajb. It's not really trying to read minds. I thought there might have been some technical reason. In my opinion it would have been easier to grasp if both << and >> had the same effect and >>> was used for sign bit.

Comment: There's usually no technical reason for language design decisions.  It's a judgment call on what the designer thinks will make the language easier to use, easier to read, less prone to errors, more powerful, and in many cases just what the designer thinks is prettiest.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the questions that you didn't ask :-)

Q: Why is there no `<<<`?

A1: Because `<<` performs the appropriate reverse operation for both `>>` and `>>>`.

- `>> N` is equivalent to divide by 2<sup>N</sup> for a signed integer
- `>>> N` is equivalent to divide by 2<sup>N</sup> for an unsigned integer
- `<< N` is equivalent to multiply by 2<sup>N</sup> for *both* signed *and* unsigned integers

A2:  Because the sign bit is on the left hand end, so "extending" it when you shift leftwards is nonsensical.  (Rotating would make sense, but Java doesn't have *any* "rotate" operators.  Reasons: C precedent, lack of hardware support in some instruction sets, rotation is rarely needed in Java code.)

Q: Why does only one of `>>` and `>>>` to sign extension

A: Because if they both did (or neither did) then you wouldn't need two operators.

---

Now for **your** questions (I think):

Q: Why did they choose `>>` to do sign extension and not `>>>`?

A: This is really unanswerable.  As far as we know, there is no extant publicly available *contemporaneous* record of the original Oak / Java language design decisions.  At best, we have to rely on the memory of James Gosling ... and his willingness to answer questions.  AFAIK, the question has not been asked.

But my *conjecture* is that since Java integer types are (mostly) signed, it was thought that the `>>` operator would be used more often.  In hindsight, I think Gosling et al got that right.

But this was NOT about copying C or C++.  In those languages, there is only one right-shift operator (`>>`) and its behavior for signed integers is *implementation defined!!*.  The `>>>` operator in Java was designed to fix that problem; i.e. remove the portability problem of C / C++ `>>`.

(Reference: Section [6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7) of the draft C11 Language spec.)

Next your comment:

> I would assume `<<` and `>>` should have the same implementation.   By same implementation I mean same process but opposite direction.

That is answered above.  From the perspective of *useful* functionality, `>>` and `<<` *do* perform the same process for signed numbers but in different direction; i.e. division versus multiplication.  And for unsigned numbers `<<<` corresponds to `>>` in the same way?

Why the difference?  It is basically down to the mathematics of 2's complement and unsigned binary representations.

Note that you *cannot* perform the mathematical inverse of `>>` or `>>>`.  Intuitively, these operators *throw away* the bits on the right end.  Once thrown away, those bits cannot be recovered.

Q: So why don't they make `<<` (or a hypothetical `<<<`) "extend" the right hand bit?

A: Because:

- It is not useful.  (I cannot think of any mainstream use-cases for extending the right hand bits of a number.)
- There is typically no hardware support (... because it is not useful!)